# How to enable API use in salesforce environment

Tags: api, profile, wsdl

I'm trying to access the partner API on a salesforce environment, but I can not find the **API Enabled** option. I did find it on an other environment.

How can I enable/add this option?

[image: example]

Example where the API isn't available:
[image: api not found]

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify your edition in your question, but that's likely the cause of this issue.

See [Salesforce Editions with API Access](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005140&type=1).

> To use the API, your organization must be on one of the following 4 editions (the API is enabled by default):
>
> - Enterprise Edition
> - Unlimited Edition
> - Developer Edition
> - Performance Edition
>
> Editions with no API Access
>
> - Contact Edition
> - Group Edition
> - Professional Edition

Comment: Probably also worth noting that if you're making an app that will be listed on the App Exchange, your app (after passing the security review) can make certain API calls even when installed in a Group or Professional Edition org. See [API Access in Group and Professional Editions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_api_access.htm)